# NGramPhraseQuery using Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I perform an[NGramPhraseQuery](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/NGramPhraseQuery.html) using Elasticsearch.

Comment: Your question is too vague. Please explain your exact problem and what you've tried so far so we can better help you.

Comment: i used phrase match in elastic search but actually i want to perform NGramPhraseQuery which is available in lucene version 3.5.Is NGramPhraseQuery available in elastic search?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29635635/elasticsearch-query-issue-with-ngram does it help you?

Answer (score 0):

Please can you tell me what exactly you want to know??I think you are looking forward to use Ngram Analyzer in Elasticsearch.

Step1.Put your analyzer to respected index.

```
    curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/test' -d '
{
    "settings" : {
        "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" : {
                "my_ngram_analyzer" : {
                    "tokenizer" : "my_ngram_tokenizer"
                }
            },
            "tokenizer" : {
                "my_ngram_tokenizer" : {
                    "type" : "nGram",
                    "min_gram" : "2",
                    "max_gram" : "3",
                    "token_chars": [ "letter", "digit" ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'

curl 'localhost:9200/test/_analyze?       pretty=1&analyzer=my_ngram_analyzer' -d 'FC Schalke 04'
         # FC, Sc, Sch, ch, cha, ha, hal, al, alk, lk, lke, ke, 04
```

It will break your text in provided min_gram & max_gram.In this case it is 2,3 respectively.